# Flatsome theme catalog image size

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, media-queries, media

Does anybody knows how set proportional (1:1) dimensions for catalogue images that fit in all scenarios in Flatsome theme? set width and height on image or box-image with cover fit is not solution. In image settings 1:1 or checking uncropped is also not solution.

We don't have all images 1:1 but I don't want to write 10 media queries to cover all scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was:

set default images to uncroped, also check in catalogue settings "equal image heights".

Answer (score 0):

```
.catalogue-image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; 
}

.catalogue-image-container::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%; 
}

.catalogue-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

you can use this css. you need to change the class name for catalogue-image-container and catalogue-image as per your requirements.

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer ..I found solution without code